# Cordova plugin error on Android - cordova-plugin-secure-key-store

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm having issues storing an Oauth web token using the cordova-plugin-secure-key-store plugin.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-secure-key-store

When I'm setting a key I get the following:-

```
cordova.plugins.SecureKeyStore.set(function (res) {
    console.log('success: ' + res);
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
}, "sessionToken", JSON.stringify(token));
```

index.js?v=1.0.2:90 Error: {"code":1,"api-level":23,"message":Error while finalizing cipher}

When I try to retrieve the key (that obviously doesn't exist), I get:-

```
cordova.plugins.SecureKeyStore.get(function (res) {
    savedToken = JSON.parse(res);
    console.log('success: ' + savedToken);
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
}, "sessionToken");
```

Error: {"code":9,"api-level":23,"message":null}

I'm probably doing something stupid but I can't seem to find any answers. Cheers for any help or pointers!

Comment: [Some issue on the project you mentioned](https://github.com/pradeep1991singh/cordova-plugin-secure-key-store/issues/15) suggests that this can be caused by some illegal characters somewhere in you parameters. Could you share (at least a part of) the value you try to insert? Does it work with storing e.g. "test" in there?

Comment: The problem is happening when the alias has /. After removing the / it will work as expected.